# Mapping a list into a phase diagram

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Consider the following list

```
list = {{1,1,1},{1,2,1},{1,3,2},{1,4,2},
        {2,1,1},{2,2,2},{2,3,2},{2,4,2},
        {3,1,1},{3,2,2},{3,3,3},{3,4,3},
        {4,1,2},{4,2,3},{4,3,3},{4,4,3}};
```

The list is composed of sublists in the form of `{x,y,value}`, where the first and second element are the coordinates, and the third element is a value which should be assigned in the phase diagram.

In the example above, I would a different color to be assigned to a different number (say 1 - blue, 2 - red, 3 - green).

The result should look like the following

[image]

This is a simplified example of a much larger data set, with very small spacings between the {x,y} values, which should eventually produce several colors that represent phases.

Comment: Why do you call this a "phase plot"?

Comment: @Stork, changed to phase diagram, if u know a better terminology please edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

E.g.

```
Graphics[{{Blue, Red, Green}[[#3]], Disk[{#2, #}, 1/3]} & @@@ list,
 AxesOrigin -> {1, 1}/2, FrameStyle -> FontSize -> 28,
 FrameTicks -> {Range[4], Range[4], None, None}, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Y", 24], Rotate[Style["X", 24], -90 °]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps it is personal preference, but would it be better practice to use the option `RotateLabel -> False` rather than rotate the "X" label manually?

Answer (score 3):

This approach might appeal

```
BubbleChart[list /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {y, x, z}, 
 BubbleSizes -> {0.25, 0.25}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, r}, 
   Switch[{x, y, r}, {_, _, 1}, Blue, {_, _, 2}, Red, {_, _, 3}, 
    Green]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {Range[4], Range[4], None, None}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Y", "X"}, RotateLabel -> False]
```

[image]

You can adjust the space between bubbles by changing the `BubbleSizes`.

Answer (score 3):

**Using `MapThread`:**

```
list = {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 
    2}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 4, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3}, {3, 4, 
    3}, {4, 1, 2}, {4, 2, 3}, {4, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 3}};

cols = {1 -> Blue, 2 -> Red, 3 -> Green};

t = MapThread[{Lookup[cols, #3, Black]
     , Disk[{#2, #1}, 0.4]} &
   , list // Transpose];

Graphics[t
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameTicks -> {{Range[4], None}
   , {Range[4], None}
   }
 , FrameLabel -> {{Rotate["X", -π/2], None}
   , {"C", None}}
 ]
```

---

Another way could be to use `Epilog` in an otherwise empty `ListPlot`.

```
newList = 
 list /. {x_, y_, z_} :> {Lookup[cols, z, Black], Point@{y, x}} // 
  Flatten

ListPlot[{}
 , PlotRange -> {{0.5, 4.5}, {0.5, 4.5}}
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameTicks -> {{Range[4], None}
   , {Range[4], None}
   }
 , FrameLabel -> {{Rotate["X", -\[Pi]/2], None}
   , {"C", None}}
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[70]
   , newList
   }
 ]
```

---

Or rearrange the data further to plot it using `ListPlot` while incorporating `PlotMarkers`.

```
t2 = Transpose[{list[[All, 2]], list[[All, 1]]}]
t3 = Lookup[cols, list[[All, 3]], Black]
ListPlot[List /@ t2
 , PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, 0.4]
    , ImageSize -> 80]}
 , PlotStyle -> t3
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , PlotRange -> {{0.5, 4.5}, {0.5, 4.5}}
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameTicks -> {{Range[4], None}
   , {Range[4], None}
   }
 , FrameLabel -> {{Rotate["X", -\[Pi]/2], None}
   , {"C", None}}
 
 ]
```

---

Result:

[image]